# How can l use sklearn k-means for 3D (RGB) dataset?

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, k-means, pca

l want to do clustering for cifar-10 data (3D image) (RGB) using [sklearn k-means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) . But since my data are 3D images l don't know how to apply k-means on the three channels RGB. Do l need to apply PCA then get 2D data after that apply k-means ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

k-means is not restricted to 2d data.

Why do you think it is?

Comment: Make it a 3d data set, cluster.

Comment: how can l do that ?

Comment: reshape the matrix.

Comment: So reshape it to `(32*32, 3)`

Comment: Reshaping doesn't really change it. It's just interpretation.